# Set value in Setter according to number of column in ResultSetMetaData

Tags: java

I am looking for dynamic approach in order to set the values in setter method, in which I fetch the total number of column from `ResultSetMetaData`, on based of those result, I want to set the values in corresponding setter method. I already prepared the snippet in my utility class.

```
public Integer extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    for(int i = 1 ; i <= columnCount ; i++){
        SQLColumn column = new SQLColumn();
        String columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
    }
    return columnCount;
}
```

Now the scenario is I want to set `Pay_codes` Of Employees, now there are total 95 paycode, but it differs in case of employees.

For example, Regular employees has 13 paycode, where as contactual employee has 6 codes, similarly society employees has 8 paycodes.

Now I need to show the list of paycodes on behalf of employee.
I passed `EmployeeCode` and I got the result.

Now The **problem**
whether I set all the column in my RowMapper like below

```
Paycode pc=new PayCode();
if(rs.getString("ESIC") != null){  
    pc.setESICCode(rs.getString("ESIC"));
}
if(rs.getString("EPF") != null){  
    pc.setEPFCode(rs.getString("EPF"));
}
if(rs.getString("Allowance") != null){  
    pc.setAllowance(rs.getString("Allowance"));
}
and many more columns........till 300+ lines
```

This seems very bad approach, because, Paycode can be increase or decrease as per client request.

So, I am looking for 2-3 line of dynamic code which set the values in setter according to the column name inside "ResultSetMetaData".So Kindly suggest me the best approach and help me to achieve the same.

However I am thinking of generic implementation, is generic do some magic, If yes > then how? please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
private void mapFields(PayCode p, String setterName, Object value) {
    Method[] methods = PayCode.class.getDeclaredMethods();
    for(Method  method: methods){
        if(method.getName().contains(setterName)){
            try {
                method.invoke(p, value);
                break;
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So you use Java reflection API with `PayCode.class.getDeclaredMethods` to get class methods, and then you iterate through method names searching for method that contains name of the property.
Once you find it you set the value to the object with `method.invoke(p, value)`, and exit the loop.

You can make things faster if you store `PayCode.class.getDeclaredMethods()`, and then make a hash set with method name as a key, and method as a value `Map<String, Method>`:

```
static Map<String, Method> mapFields(Class clazz) {
    Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
    Map<String, Method> result = new HashMap<>();
    for(Method  method: methods){
        String methodName = method.getName();
        if(methodName.indexOf("set") == 0){
            result.put(methodName.substring(3), method);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

and then use it:

```
Map<String, Method> fields = mapFields(PayCode.class);
if(fields.containsKey(name)){
    try {
        fields.get(name).invoke(p, value);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This only works as long as all values has the type `String`. OP should clarify if all of the _many more columns_ in _300+ lines_ have the type `String`.

Comment: Well explanation @user987339, but i want to match the columnname and then generate the setters against it, I already maintain an ENUM of all 95 paycodes and I using them as Key and against each key I bind a method inside MAP, now I want to match the column name after query execution, If my columnName matched with Key in Map, then its corresponding setter will generated

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use reflection

   ```
   package com.test;

   import java.lang.reflect.Method;

   class PayCode {
       private String esic;
       private String epf;

       public String getEsic() {
           return esic;
       }

       public void setEsic(String esic) {
           this.esic = esic;
       }

       public String getEpf() {
           return epf;
       }

       public void setEpf(String epf) {
           this.epf = epf;
       }

       @Override
       public String toString() {
           return "PayCode [esic=" + esic + ", epf=" + epf + "]";
       }

   }

   public class DynamicSetter {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           PayCode payCode = new PayCode();

           try {
               /**
                * Here you can take "set" hardcoded and generate suffix "Esic"
                * dynamically, may be using apache StringUtils or implement using
                * Substring, based on your class setter methods.
                */
               Method esicMethod = PayCode.class.getMethod("set" + "Esic", String.class);
               esicMethod.invoke(payCode, "Test Paycode");

               System.out.println("Check paycode in object : " + payCode);

           } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

       }
   }
   ```
2. You can use HashMap<> to add all pay code in that. You can also implement gtter for each pay code to read from HashMap.

   ```
   package com.test;

   import java.sql.ResultSet;
   import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
   import java.sql.SQLException;
   import java.util.HashMap;
   import java.util.Map;

   class Employee {
       private Map<String, String> payCodes = new HashMap<>();
       private String epf;

       public String getEsic() {
           return payCodes.get("ESIC");
       }

       public String getEpf() {
           return payCodes.get("EPF");
       }

       public Map<String, String> getPayCodes() {
           return payCodes;
       }



   }

   public class DynamicSetter {
       public static void main(String[] args) {

       }

       public static Integer extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {

           while(rs.next()) {

               Employee e = new Employee();
               Map<String, String> payCodes = e.getPayCodes();


               //set app paycode in payCodes, you can use column name as key and fetch value from result set.


           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: This only works as long as all values has the type `String`. OP should clarify if all of the _many more columns_ in _300+ lines_ have the type `String`.

Comment: I have provided example, obviously developer can modify as per need.

Comment: Yes, it's an example. But if OP has to write for each type additional code, is it still that generic? OP said: _I am looking for 2-3 line of dynamic code_. Just a hint.

Comment: Thank you so much guys and yes all the 95 paycodes are string